# How Do I SELECT Values From The Database similar to the values of the login user

Tags: php, mysql

I got `user` Table which contains fields like `userName`,`department` and so on. So My question is if login user belongs to Computer Sci & Technology `department` then how do i select all the user who belongs to the Computer Sci & Technology `department` from the database

```
userName       courseID           department
sachin             1        Civil Engineering
virat              2        Computer Sci & Technology
rohit              2        Computer Sci & Technology

<form role="form" method="post" action="user/checkLogin.php">
    <input type="text" name="u_ID" value="" placeholder="Unique-ID">
    <input type="password" name="dob" value="" placeholder="Birth Date  (DD/MM/YY)"> </form>
```

so the result should be virat and rohit

Comment: What query did you try that didn't work?

Comment: $sql=" SELECT * FROM  user WHERE department = '".$_SESSION['userid']."'";

Comment: @AbhiBurk now i get you. You mean an already **LOGGED** in user.

Comment: yes if the user has LOGGED in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it could be done. step by step

```
<?php
session_start(); 

//your connection
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbname") or die("Couldn't make connection.");

//assuming $userID is user id of logged in user
$userID = $_SESSION['userid'];

//table of user who has logged in
$query_loguser = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE userid = '$userID'");
$row_loguser = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_loguser);

//department of logged in user
$department = $row_loguser['department'];

//users from same department as logged in user
$query_depuser = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `department` = '$department'");
$row_depuser = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_depuser);


?>

<?php do { ?>

<?php echo $row_depuser['userName']; //list all users who are from same department as logged in user ?><br />

<?php } while ($row_depuser = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_depuser));   ?>
```

Comment: this is static statement i want dyanamic as i have many departments in my database

Comment: The statement will select all users whose department is `Computer Sci & Technology` i.e. virat and rohit.  if they are 20 it will select all of them. if they are 100 it will still pick all of them. if you add one to twenty it will pick 21. therefore it is dynamic, unless i dont understand your question?

Comment: depending upon the login users department weather it may be cs or e&tc i want to select those department users which are similar to login users department

Comment: and if login user belongs to Civil Engineering department then how would i do that

Comment: check my question

Comment: plz anyone here ?

Comment: @AbhiBurk i have edited my answer